# How does tampermonkey or greasemonkey work

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

How does tampermonkey or greasemonkey inject javascript into the webpage? Does it do it through console object? Is there another way, a better way of doing it?

Comment: In Chrome the only way is injecting a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi).

Comment: The basic/best approach is that the userscript operates in a separate env than page's JS, and both sets of JS can use the DOM but not each other. ... However, **It varies a lot.**  Look up "isolated world" (Chrome) and sandbox (Firefox/Mozilla). ... Scripts can also be injected straight into the page -- usually/hopefully wrapped in an anonymous function.